Linear Algebra Done Right, 4th Edition, problem 7.D.11
In the following problem (from Axler's "Linear Algebra Done Right", 4th Edition, problem 11 of section 7D), $V$ is a finite-dimensional inner product space:

Suppose  ∈ ℒ(). Prove that  is a unitary operator if and only if
{ ∶  ∈  and ‖‖ ≤ 1} = { ∈  ∶ ‖‖ ≤ 1}.

I've already proved the forward direction. As for the backward direction we have $||Sv||=||v||.||S(\frac{v}{||v||})||\leq ||v||$, but I'm stuck showing that the inequality is in fact an equality (hence $S$ is unitary), so any help would be appreciated.

@Nothingspecial But how should this be applied to the hypothesis?

@Nothingspecial I'm trying to prove the other direction, ie. $S$ is unitary.

I have a feeling @terran will come up with a good answer…

@TedBlack Me too!!

You are getting close to being reported.

By the comments, $S$ is surjective.This comes from the fact that if $v\in V-\{0\}$ then the hypothesis implies $\frac{v}{|v|} = Su$ for some $u\in V$ with $|u|\leq 1$, and thus $v = S(||v||u)$.
Surjectivity implies $S$ is injective too. This happens by the finite-dimensionality. (It can not hold for infinite-dimensional vector spaces, such as infinite-dimensional Hilbert spaces). Now you proved $||Sv||\leq ||v||$ which implies $||v|| = ||S(S^{-1}v)||\leq ||S^{-1}v||$.
Now assume $||v||=1$. Then by the condition, $||S^{-1}v||\leq 1$, implying $||S^{-1}v|| = 1$. This shows the inverse is unitary. Now $||v|| = ||S^{-1}Sv|| = ||Sv||$ for any $v$.

I don't see why ||S^-1 v||\leq 1, can you explain it better?

According to the condition, if $||v|| = 1$, then it lies in ${v\in V : |v| \leq 1} = { Su : u\in V & |u|\leq 1}$. Thus $v = Su$ for some $u$ whose lenght is $\leq 1$. By bijectivity, $u = S^{-1}v$ i

I apologize. I deleted the comment because I had a misunderstanding of which direction of the proof statement is backward. I did not see your answer while deleting. Anyways, that $S$ is surjective comes from the fact that all unit vectors of $V$ are in $\text{Range}(S)$. I would want you edit your answer so that it remains useful for future visitors. Thank you.
